# Would like to understand why this "setInterval" in my code isnt working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to control the refresh rate of drawn objects using javascript in canvas. I've gone over the *w3.school* explanations and examples as to how to clear screen and use set interval in regards to canvas but im not sure why the below "`setInterval`" is not actually running the "`generateGame()`" function every 1 second.

```js
buildCanvas();

  function buildCanvas(){
    let c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    let drwMthd = c.getContext('2d');

    setInterval(generateGame(c, drwMthd), 1000);

    function generateGame(c, drwMthd){
      refreshC(c, drwMthd);
      drawObjects(drwMthd);
      console.log('reset');
    }
  }

  function refreshC(c, drwMthd){
    drwMthd.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    console.log('all cleared');
  }

  function drawObjects(drwMthd){
    boxGenerator(10, 10, 10, 10, "green", drwMthd);
    boxGenerator(1, 1, 10, 10, "green", drwMthd);
    console.log('all drawn');
  }

  function boxGenerator(top, left, width, height, color, drwMthd){
    drwMthd.fillStyle = color;
    drwMthd.fillRect(top, left, width, height, color);
  }
```

```css
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="60" style="background-color: white">
```

I also used a `console.log` to print reset every 1 second to test if it was the actual drawing that was messing the interval up.

```
function buildCanvas(){
    let c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    let drwMthd = c.getContext('2d');

    setInterval(generateGame(c, drwMthd), 1000);

    function generateGame(c, drwMthd){
      refreshC(c, drwMthd);
      drawObjects(drwMthd);
      console.log('reset');
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but as an aside - you should probably be using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for this: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/

Comment: You miss the function(){} inside your setInterval

Comment: setInterval/setTimeOut  needs a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` needs a function reference. The problem is that you are not passing a function reference, instead you're invoking the `generateGame` function. And since the `generateGame` function doesn't explicitly return anything, it returns `undefined`. 
So you're setting an interval to an undefined function.

A solution would be to pass an anonymous function that calls the generateGame function :

```
setInterval(function () {
    generateGame(c, drwMthd)
    }, 1000);
```

```js
function buildCanvas(){
    let c, drwMthd;
    /*let c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    let drwMthd = c.getContext('2d'); */

    setInterval(function () {
    generateGame(c, drwMthd)
    }, 1000);

    function generateGame(c, drwMthd){
    /*
      refreshC(c, drwMthd);
      drawObjects(drwMthd);*/
      console.log('reset');
    }
}
buildCanvas();
```

Answer (score 1):

You execute the `generateGame` function instead of binding it and then the `setInterval` treats its return value, which is `void`.

To pass parameters, you need to use the `bind` keyword. Notice that the first element is the scope of `this` the function should operate with.

```js
function buildCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var drawMethod = canvas.getContext('2d');
    setInterval(generateGame.bind(this, canvas, drawMethod), 1000);
    function generateGame(c, drwMthd) {
        console.log(c, drwMthd);
    }
}
buildCanvas();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer Below Fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/bx48p8LL/)

```
setInterval(function(){
    generateGame(c, drwMthd)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: "Pika Pika" :P :D